# status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
root@93272a1da547:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n fabrep -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

While trying to instantiate my chaincode, I am getting the following error:

```
2018-06-19 09:03:09.526 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2018-06-19 09:03:09.526 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = chaincode error (status: 500, message: cannot get package for chaincode (fabrep:1.0))
```

Can anyone tell what this means? and how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First check if chaincode is installed on the peer
- `$ peer chaincode list --installed`
- And ran the `instantiate` command with the exact name of the installed chaincode

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the chaincode is installed first on the peer before attempting to instantiate.

Use the install command:

`peer chaincode install ...`

You can use the documentation of here as a guide: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-install