# Importing bna file: cannot get package for chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Some time ago a created a bna file based on https://github.com/johnwalicki/IoT-AssetTracking-Perishable-Network-Blockchain/tree/master/Blockchain

Now I want to import a bna file on a different server.

```
$ composer network install --archiveFile perishable-network.bna --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1
$ composer network start --networkName perishable-network  --networkVersion 1.0.0 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: cannot get package for chaincode (perishable-network:1.0.0)
```

I am aware of this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50925777/status-500-message-cannot-get-package-for-chaincode) but wouldn't know how to apply this (peer chaincode install) to my specific situation.

**docker ps** directly **via VNC on the Ubuntu 18.04 VM** where I start the composer-playground command:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar$2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

**docker ps via SSH** from my laptop (Mac):

```
peter@asset-tracker:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
3167a355ed2d        hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.2.1       "peer node start"        14 hours ago        Up 14 hours         0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
75bf0cc3cdd1        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb:0.4.10   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours         4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
33322a1d07cd        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:1.2.1    "orderer"                14 hours ago        Up 14 hours         0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
05e542111f21        hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.2.1         "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   14 hours ago        Up 14 hours         0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.org1.example.com
```

Comment: It seems like Composer-Cli could not get a connection with fabric network. Can you add the output of `docker ps` command?

Comment: added the outputs from VNC viewer and SSH, which are different for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with the first error on the `composer network start` command:

" Error: cannot get package for chaincode (perishable-network:1.0.0) "

This says that the network with that name and version can't be found on the Peer - so either it isn't there or there is some mismatch in the name/version.

If you run the command `composer archive list -a perishable-network.bna` you will see the exact details from the bna, and you will see any mismatch with your `composer network start` command.

If the name./version are OK could also check the file system on the Peer to see it is actually successfully installed: `docker exec peer0.org1.example.com ls /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes`

If the package is not visible from the command above then you will need to re-run the `composer network install ...` command - then recheck the file system on the peer using the previous command.

Have you stopped or restarted the Fabric between the `composer network install` and `composer network start` commands?  Please see this [previous Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data) posting which explains how the startFabric.sh script works.